# Pandas: Create a shift indicator, omitting the first value of a group

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create an indicator variable that detects changes in a column, using groupby, that ignores the first instance of arriving at a new group.

```
import pandas as pd
# generate data
case = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                  'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 1, 0])
year = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]

# generate expectation
expectation = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

dict = {'case': case, 'y': y, 'year': year, 'expectation': expectation}
# build df
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# build a changing case id
df['case_id'] = ((~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1)).cumsum()

# current attempt
df['counter'] = ( df.groupby(['case'])["case_id"].shift(0) != df.groupby(['case'])["case_id"].shift(1) ).map({True: 1, False: 0})
```

Result:

```
counter expectation
    1   0
    0   0
    1   1
    0   0
    1   0
    0   0
    1   1
    0   0
    1   0
    0   0
    0   0
    1   1
```

Edit:

Please see this answer for those looking for something similar in the future!

[Pandas: Detect value change in string column with groupby; ignoring first entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232950/pandas-detect-value-change-in-string-column-with-groupby-ignoring-first-entry/68232964?noredirect=1#comment120592779_68232964)

Comment: Could you explain me why the last line `C  0  2019` is 0 and not 1, please?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo -- fixed; you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first value of a group can be done with `head(1)`:

```
# remove cumsum, convert to int
df['case_id'] = ((~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1)).astype(int)

# omit the first value of a group
df.loc[df.groupby('case').head(1).index, 'case_id'] = 0
```

```
>>> df
   case  y  year  expectation  case_id
0     A  0  2016            0        0
1     A  1  2017            0        0
2     A  0  2018            1        1
3     A  0  2019            0        0
4     B  0  2016            0        0
5     B  1  2017            0        0
6     B  0  2018            1        1
7     B  0  2019            0        0
8     C  0  2016            0        0
9     C  0  2017            0        0
10    C  1  2018            0        0
11    C  0  2019            1        1

>>> df['expectation'].eq(df['case_id']).all()
True
```

Comment: Actually -- anyway to generalize this off of any value; like even a string? This only works in the case of using `case_id` which is binary here.