# Pandas: Detect value change in string column with groupby; ignoring first entry

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create an indicator variable that detects changes in a column, using groupby, that ignores the first instance of arriving at a new group.

```
import pandas as pd
# generate data
case = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
                  'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])

val1 = pd.Series(['Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat1',
               'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat2', 'Cat1',
               'Cat2', 'Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat2'])

expectation = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

dict = {'case': case, 'val1': val1, 'expectation' : expectation}
# build df
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)


# my attempt
df['my_test'] = df.groupby('case')["val1"].shift(1) != df.groupby('case')["val1"].shift(0)
# recode
df['my_test'] = df['my_test'].map({True: 1, False: 0})
# check results
df
```

My attempt gets close -- but the first value of each group is still detected as a change; is there a way to do this directly in Pandas without doing another set of code to perhaps find the indices of the first value of each group and then re-setting each value back to zero (instead of 1 like it is here)

```
    case    val1    expectation my_test
0   A   Cat1    0   1
1   A   Cat1    0   0
2   A   Cat1    0   0
3   A   Cat1    0   0
4   B   Cat1    0   1
5   B   Cat2    1   1
6   B   Cat2    0   0
7   B   Cat1    1   1
8   C   Cat2    0   1
9   C   Cat1    1   1
10  C   Cat1    0   0
11  C   Cat2    1   1

# to ingest
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Comment: Also don't assign anything to `dict` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try testing both [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) *and* [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to keep `not equals` from matching the `NaN` created by`groupby shift`:

```
s = df.groupby('case')["val1"].shift(1)
df['out'] = (s.ne(df['val1']) & s.notna()).astype(int)
```

Or use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the `NaN` values from `val1`:

```
df['out'] = (
    df.groupby('case')["val1"].shift(1)
        .fillna(df['val1'])
        .ne(df['val1']).astype(int)
)
```

`df`:

```
   case  val1  expectation  out
0     A  Cat1            0    0
1     A  Cat1            0    0
2     A  Cat1            0    0
3     A  Cat1            0    0
4     B  Cat1            0    0
5     B  Cat2            1    1
6     B  Cat2            0    0
7     B  Cat1            1    1
8     C  Cat2            0    0
9     C  Cat1            1    1
10    C  Cat1            0    0
11    C  Cat2            1    1
```